Why Does Adding Epsilon Not Prevent Zero Division in Integer Division?
I am aware that there are better methods to handle division by zero in integer division. However, for educational purposes, I am curious about why adding a small epsilon value (1e-7) to the divisor in my function causes runtime errors instead of preventing division by zero. Here's the code snippet:
def kangaroo(x1, v1, x2, v2):
    if (x2-x1) % (v1-v2) == 0 and (x2-x1) / ((v1-v2) + 1e-7) >= 0: # adding epsilon
        return "YES"
    else: 
        return "NO"

In this function, I attempted to add 1e-7 to the divisor (v1-v2) to prevent a division by zero. My expectation was that this would allow the division to proceed without error even when (v1-v2) is zero. I also tried using a larger epsilon value like 1e-1, but this approach still leads to runtime errors in certain scenarios. Can someone explain why this specific implementation fails and discuss the implications of using such a small epsilon in integer arithmetic, and why even larger epsilon values like 1e-1 do not solve the issue?

It's a hackerrank question, Number Line Jumps. I get a runtime error in a test case while submitting

causes runtime errors Are we supposed to guess what these errors are?  Please post them.

When I test the function in my env with all parameters being the same, I also encounter an "integer modulo by zero" error.

I also encounter an "integer modulo by zero" error Don't make us guess where this error happens.  Post the full error traceback message.

Also, the error "integer modulo by zero" tells you that the problem is with modulus, not division...

yes, i just focused the division and didn't think much about modulus.

If you only test the sign of the result of the division, then there's no need to divide. Multiplying would give you the same sign, without the problem of 0.

So you do v1-v2+epsilon to avoid division by zero, but what if v1-v2 equals -epsilon? Then by adding epsilon you are causing a division by zero. Your epsilon just adds another case for the code to crash.

@Elerium115 From the question: "... in integer division ...", so this will never be a problem.

These kinds of problems are just perfect for a [mre]. You have provided the code, now you just need to provide the inputs that trigger the problem you're seeing and provide the stacktrace of the exception that's being raised formatted in a [code block]. Thank you Ömer!

This approach WILL cause runtime errors. When v1-v2 is zero, the first condition (x2-x1) % (v1-v2) will fail to execute and cause the runtime error. The code you have written will work well when v1-v2 is non zero and divides x2-x1. In that case the epsilon would automatically get added to v1-v2. This error is independent of the magnitude of epsilon chosen, since the first condition would've failed even before we evaluate the second part.
A better solution would be:
if (x2-x1) % ((v2-v1) + epsilon) == 0:
    return "YES"
else:
    return "NO"

Or maybe this:
if (v2-v1) == 0:
   v2 += epsilon

if (x2-x1) % (v2-v1) == 0:
    return "YES"
else:
    return "NO"

The second solution adds epsilon only when the difference is zero, while the other when does it irrespective of what the value is, since for a difference of order 1e-4 or higher, an addition of 1e-7 would not create much of a difference. The first approach may some milliseconds on execution depending on how you structure your code.

Arguably, if the presumed denominator is 0, you can return a result immediately. There's no reason to "tweak" the denominator and perform a ceremonial division just to get the predetermined result.

If you want to use epsilon only when needed, you could use v2-v1 or epsilon.

Yes. These suggestions would also be pretty neat.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk Why did you roll back? That seems rather rude. This isn't your answer.

@nocomment: The answer is clearer the way it was. It wasn't the answerer's edit either. I won't insist though, if the answerer really prefers it that way they can revert the edit and I won't roll it back again.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk The edit wasn't written by the answerer, but they approved and thus applied it. Don't you think that shows they do prefer it?

@nocomment: Well, it might in many cases, but some users kind of feel bullied by suggested edits. In this case, I felt the answer used the expression (v2-v1) for clarity to match the question's use of it.

v2-v1 == 0 is objectively better because it tests whether the divisor will be zero, which v2 == v1 does not. With IEEE-754 floating-point, v2-v1 == 0 is true if and only if v2 == v1 is true (which is a major purpose of having subnormal values), but Python is not guaranteed to use IEEE-754 rules. Even on systems that largely follow IEEE-754, subnormal results may be flushed to zero, which can cause v2-v1 to be zero in some cases when v2 == v1 is not true (albeit not with integer values for v1 and v2).
